# Interpreting the sum as a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, functions, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Consider the manifold $M = \{(x,x^2) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and for $\varepsilon > 0$ let $M_{\varepsilon}  = \bigcup_{p \in M} B_{\varepsilon}(p)$. How can I find $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the map
$$
F \colon NM \cap (\mathbb{R}^2 \times B_{\varepsilon}(0)) \rightarrow M_{\varepsilon} \colon (p,w) \mapsto p + w
$$
is a diffeomorphism? The definition of the normal bundle is
$$
N M = \{ (p,w) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 : p \in M \text{ and } w \in (T_{p} \, M)^{\bot} \}.
$$

Comment: Think about how far you can travel (inward) along normal lines without meeting other normal segments. Curvature of the parabola near its vertex will be the controlling factor.

Answer (score 1):

To get a diffeomorphism, you'll actually need a bijective (in particular, injective) immersion. Consider first the question of immersivity. Parametrize the curve $\alpha$ by arclength and then your map is given by
$f(s,t) = \alpha(s) + t N(s)$ (where $N$ is the unit normal). You can check (using the Frenet equations) that $df$ has rank $<2$ at $(s,t)$ only when $t=1/\kappa(s)$. So if $t<1/\kappa_{\text{max}}=1/2$, the map will be an immersion.

Now check explicitly that if $t<1/2$ the normal line segments of length $t$ will never intersect, so the map is one-to-one. (By symmetry, the worst case scenario will be points $(\pm u,u^2)$.) Intuitively, since the parabola spreads apart, rather than getting close to itself, the curvature is the controlling phenomenon.